# Jboss load system properties from file

Tags: jboss

Can I make jboss load system properties from a file without writing any **explicit code** for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
In JbossAS versions prior to 7.x there is [PropertiesService](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/PropertiesService). It's dead simple to use. I am using it with JBoss 5.1.0.GA, and it works like a charm.
Unfortunatelly PropertiesService mbean is absent in JBossAS 7.x, but there are other ways as described in [official admin guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-SystemProperties).

[Here](https://community.jboss.org/message/750350#750350) is another solution. Post author claims it's possible to list your properties files in command line while starting server instance:

```
./standalone.sh --properties=1.properties --properties=2.properties
```

and their contents should be added to System Properties.